# How to derive this formula?

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-explanation

In this picture a card-roulette type game is played and the expected value is calculated using a formula which is not explained:
Do you know how it is derived?[image]

Comment: The equation outlined in yellow seems to be $\frac{1-x^k y^{n-k}}{1-x}$ (same as the left-hand member of the following displayed equation in larger type), but I cannot find enough context to be sure what $x$ and $y$ represent, in terms of the bet on cards.

Comment: You really should have told us what book you are quoting! But since others may be eager to know right away, I'll save you the trouble this time: it's from [Magical  Mathematics](https://www.amazon.com/Magical-Mathematics-Mathematical-Animate-Tricks/dp/0691169772) by Perci Diaconis and Ron Graham.

Comment: X and Y are the factors determining the next bet after a win or loss, X=1/2 so after a bet of 16 and a win, the next bet would be 1/2 * 16 = 8. Y=3/2 so after a loss the next bet would be 3/2 * 16 = 24. Apologies for not referencing, the book! < 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x+y=2$, then $1-x=y-1$ and as shown in the argument, the sequence $RB$ will yield the same result as $BR$.

Hence, WLOG, we can assume the sequence is first $k$ red cards, followed by $n-k$ black cards, also we can assume $A=1$. That is we keep winning the first $k$ games and then we lose the remaining $n-k$ game.

Hence the sum is

\begin{align}&\sum_{i=1}^{k} x^{i-1} -x^k\sum_{j=1}^{n-k}y^{j-1} 
\\&=\frac{(1-x^k)}{1-x}-\frac{x^k(1-y^{n-k})}{1-y}\\
&=\frac{(1-x^k)+x^k(1-y^{n-k})}{1-x}\\
&=\frac{1-x^ky^{n-k}}{1-x}\end{align}

where we have used $1-y=x-1$ in the second equality.